# Using $.proxy while still having access to what would be the original this

Tags: jquery, proxy, this

Is there a way to proxy "this" but also still have access to the "this" of the context you are now within? I typically set `this` to `self` but I was curious if there was a way to have two contexts while using $.proxy.

For example...

```
$('.something').on('click', $proxy(function() {
  // this = proxied this
  // $(this) needs to equal .something
}, this));
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a duplicate since I specifically want to know how to manage two contexts using jQuery's proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do it without a wrapper function. But why not instead saving the outer `this` outside and then use in inside the function?

```
var self = this;
$('.something').on('click', function() {
    self.doSomething();
    // this == element
});
```

Also, in that case, since you are in an event handler, you can acces the element inside the  `event` object since `this === event.currentTarget`. So you can use something like this :

```
$('.something').on('click', $proxy(function(e) {
  // this = proxied this
  // $(e.currentTarget) equal to .something
}, this));
```

Comment: I should update my question. I typically do var self = this but was curious if there was a way to do it using proxy. Your answer seems to be the best way to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `this` cannot *magically* refer to two different values.

You don't necessarily have to bind the outer `this`, there are other ways to access its value: [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

If you want to use `$.proxy` though, you can use [**`event.currentTarget`**](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) to access the element (which would normally be referred by `this`):

```
$('.something').on('click', $proxy(function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).whatever()
}, this));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the additional info. I updated my question to reflect that I was curious if there was a way to do it with $.proxy despite there being potentially better alternatives.

Comment: Well, in that case your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback, which I linked as well and lists all the possible ways to refer to `this`. Or maybe I misunderstand your comment.